# auto close HTML tags is not triggering

Tags: visual-studio-code

According to [this update](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_16#_html-close-tags), VS Code is supposed to auto close tags when the closing `>` of the opening tag is typed. Mine won't seem to do that (I'm on v1.19).

I also tried installing the package Jun Han made which is supposed to do this too, but it doesn't work. Is there a trick to getting this function to work?

Enabled extensions are:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've also experienced inconsistencies with this feature.

---

> Tag elements are now automatically closed when > of the opening tag is typed

This only *seems* to work when the file is detected as plain HTML or JS.

[image: detected as HTML]
[image: detected as JS]

> The matching closing tag is inserted when / of the closing tag is entered

This works for HTML and JavaScript, and for other formats that render HTML like Vue or Markdown.

---

There are some settings you can check if it's not working:

- Make sure `html.autoClosingTags` is `true`

  - It should be `true` by default
  - Check your user, workspace, and folder settings (maybe one is overriding it)
- If you still have the [Auto Close Tag](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-close-tag) extension installed:

  - `auto-close-tag.excludedTags`
  - `auto-close-tag.activationOnLanguage`

    - If the detected language is not HTML or JavaScript, check that it is on this list
  - `auto-close-tag.fullMode`

    - The default is `false`, but setting to `true` makes it *seem* more consistent

Comment: I tried all of these things. The only setting is html.autoClosingTags: true. My div tags won't close.

Comment: @Mel Ohh. My only other guess is that some other extension is overriding or conflicting with this feature. Can you also share your extensions list?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After reviewing the answer above, I noticed that VS Code auto-detected a different language than HTML, even though the file I was editing had the ".html" extension. After selecting HTML as the working language, the editor now auto-closes the tags.